# LXDE: Keyboard settings not loading

Tags: debian, keyboard, lxde, settings

Debian Stretch LXDE

I made some keyboard settings wich means repeat delay and interval. After system's start I have to go into the settings and at least to cancel them to have that settings loaded.

Why is that?
How can I solve it?

Solving means having the settings loaded normally as expected in the first place and by workaround in the second.

Comment: You can edit the `/etc/default/keyboard` manually see [debian wiki : keyboard](https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard) And [debian:LXDE](https://wiki.debian.org/LXDE)

Comment: I wouldn't prefer that. I made settings in the desktop's preferences. Theses settings are stored and opening the settings after system's start loads them - but as I mentioned I MUST open them on every start. Your approach is meant to be a possible workaround and that's what I'm looking for in the second place. But you mention to edit a system wide setting. At least a user profile based approach would be nice.